# Nash Equilibrium in general graphical game

Tags: graph-theory, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

Any one has any ideas about how to compute the Nash Equilibrium in general graphical game? Especially, when the graph structure is not a tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might look at this:

> Bhat, Navin AR, and Kevin Leyton-Brown. "Computing Nash equilibria of action-graph games." In *Proceedings of the 20th Conference on Uncertainty in Artificial Intelligence*, pp. 35-42. AUAI Press, 2004. ([PDF download link](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~hutter/EARG.shtml/earg/papers04-05/continuation.pdf))

An arbitrary game can be encoded as an AGG (action-graph game).
Under certain circumstances, the Jacobian of the payoff function can be
computed in polynomial time.

 
 
 
 
[image: Figs1&2]